# How to bring GEdit to front using Java on Linux

Tags: linux, xorg

Our Java/SWT-based application can launch user-editable third-party applications, e.g. editors. On Linux (CentOS 7, Gnome 3.28.2), when launching "gedit", for example, it opens fine, but behind our application's window. The strange thing is, that when launching "gedit " from a Terminal (`gnome-terminal`), GEdit comes up as front most window.

How to tell "gedit" (or others) to launch as front-most application?

**Update:**
When I launch my Java-application from the IDE (IDEA) it works as expected (Gedit is in the front). If I launch my application from a shell-script, it works as expected. If I launch the application from the .desktop file pointing to the shell-script, Gedit not just opens the file **but also shows a notification about being ready**. Maybe this somehow confuses the z-order of the application windows? Or it depends on environment variables: if launched from the .desktop file, the environment variables `DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID`, `GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE`, `GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID` are available additionally and `HISTCONTROL` is set to `ignoredups` instead of `ignorespace`, `SHLVL` is `2` instead of `4` and `TERM` is set to `dump` instead of `xterm-256color`.

Based on Stephan Schlecht's code I have found following Java code that should reproduce the problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class EditorOpener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<String, String> getenv = System.getenv();
        System.out.println(getenv);

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(500, 200);
        shell.setText("Editor Opener");
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("open gedit");

        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> new Thread(() -> {
            final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
            processBuilder.command("/usr/bin/gedit");
            final Map<String, String> environment = processBuilder.environment();
            System.out.println(environment);
            try {
                final Process process = processBuilder.start();
                process.waitFor();
            }
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start());

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

The 2 accesses to the environment variables are essential.

Comment: `but behind our application's window` maybe your application has the 'always on top' property set? You can't affect other programs startup in the way how they grab focus (window manager thing), you can execute an action after they are started (wmctrl, xdotool, etc.) or change your's program window setting (I suspect something is wrong with it and it locks focus).

Comment: @KamilCuk no, our application does not have the "always on top" property set - I can easily bring the other application to front by Alt-Tab or clicking it.

Comment: But definitely some more info would help. What gui framework do you use? How do you create the window? You will get help waaaaay faster if you create an MCVE - just strip your program until you are left with only lines needed to replicate the issue.

Comment: So it seems to depend on an environment variable. To find out which on is causing it, you can remove half of it before calling processBuilder.start() and see if it still happens. If so, reduce it by half again. If not, use the other half of the environment variables. Repeat until you find the environment var that is causing the problem. I am curious.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Just curious: can you reproduce the behind-opening? The strange thing is that I don't change any environment variable, I just access them. If I don't access them, everything is OK. Does accessing the environment variables from Java has influence on the content of the variables?

Comment: I just tried: no behind-opening on my side. I can hardly imagine that access to the environment variables has any influence on this. Does it also happen if you just remove the System.out.println? Are you using the same shell script and the same .desktop file as in my example? What's exact Java version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that our `.desktop` file contained the lines

```
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=<main-class>
```

Removing the **first line** causes the problem to disappear.

Answer (score 3):

One could now make many assumptions (e.g. the contents of the.desktop file), but maybe it's better to have a step-by-step guide on how it would work, e.g. like this:

**Testprogram**

This SWT program starts 'gedit' via Runtime.getRuntime().exec.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class EditorOpener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(500, 200);
        shell.setText("Editor Opener");
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("open gedit");

        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                String[] cmdArray = new String[] { "/usr/bin/gedit" };
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Call the Java Program**

The Java program is called from a shell script that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
java -cp /path/to/swt.jar:/path/to/classes EditorOpener
```

**.desktop file**

The .desktop file pointing to the shell file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Opener
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec='/home/stephan/Documents/opener.sh'
Categories=Application;
```

**Result**

By clicking the *open gedit* button, gedit is started as expected above all other windows.

**Demo**

The test was done on CentOS Linux 7:

```
gnome-shell --version
```

gives the output:

```
GNOME Shell 3.28.3
```

[image: gedit demo]

Answer (score 1):

There is this utility [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) that can do what you want easily.

For your use case you will use `wmctrl -a "gedit"` or something similar. From the man page:

> -a
>
> > ```
> > Switch to the desktop containing the window <WIN>, raise the window, and give it focus.
> > ```

Alternatively, you may just minimize your program and restore it again when `gedit` finishes.

Comment: I reckon we can't use wmctrl because it is not installed by default.